# Visual Studio - Image resources not showing in preferences

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image, resources

I'm trying to use png images as icons for tabs in tabControl.

I have added all the images as resouces.
[image]

But they the images do not show when i try to add them in the tabControl properities.
[image]

Can you help me what I'm missing?
Also side note I'm using MaterialSkin2 tabControl
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.2/#readme-body-tab

Comment: try and rebuild the solution

Comment: Maybe does not apply for your 3rd party control but for a regular `TabControl` you need to add the tab images to an `ImageList` component and assign that image list to the tab control.

Comment: You can mark your answer so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue by checking different demo Project.

The issue was that I had to create ImageList Component and then upload the images to the component and set the component as image list in the tabControl.

[image]

Now everytghing works fine.
[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people